# What does this mean in JavaScript: var controller = controller || {};

Tags: javascript

What does this JavaScript code mean? What does this evaluate to and what do the parentheses do?

```
 /**
 * View Controller
 * @type {Object}
 */

var controller = controller || {};
```

Comment: The *braces* `{}` are an empty object literal. The pipes `||` mean "or". If `controller` exists it's `var controller = controller;`, if not it's `var controller = {};`.

Comment: This type of thing only makes sense at the top level, by the way – when you don’t know whether `controller` is already declared in the current scope. Usually equivalent to `if (!window.controller) { window.controller = {}; }` in browsers, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion, I will use different variable names:

```
var controller = cont || {};
```

This expression will check the value of `cont` and if it is `undefined`, it will assign `{}` or an empty object to `controller`. If `cont` has a value, `controller` will be assigned that value.

Comment: Thank you. I understand much better now

Answer (score 1):

```
var controller = controller || {};
```

So it simply means that if the `controller is undefined` as default value `{}` , will be initialised to that particular variable.

here `||` is simply an `OR operator` which you might have used in conditional statements.

Comment: i get it now, thanks!